# Maven dependency module not found

Tags: java, maven, dependency-management, java-9, vert.x

I have a rather simple project structure in Maven with sub-modules:

```
/
-pom.xml
-Utils/
  -pom.xml
```

In `/pom.xml` I define properties for all sub-modules, like library versions or plugins configurations:

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>project</groupId>
    <artifactId>main</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>Utils</module>
    </modules>

    <properties>
        <java.version>10</java.version>
        <vertx.version>3.5.0</vertx.version>
    </properties>
</project>
```

In `/Utils/pom.xml` I declare the sub-module and its dependencies:

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>project</groupId>
        <artifactId>main</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>Utils</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
            <artifactId>vertx-core</artifactId>
            <version>${vertx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
            <artifactId>vertx-unit</artifactId>
            <version>${vertx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

And I declare a `module-info.java` file:

```
module util {
    requires vertx.core;
}
```

When I open the project in my IDE it works as expected, I can access the classes from the `vertx.core` package in the `Utils` module and all the dependencies are listed there.
However when I try to compile with maven by calling `mvn clean compile` it seems that the dependencies are not in the class path:

```
[INFO] Compiling 11 source files to /home/manulaiko/Programming/Java/Kalaazu/Utils/target/classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /home/manulaiko/Programming/Java/Kalaazu/Utils/src/main/java/module-info.java:[5,19] module not found: vertx.core
```

I've tried (without success) to:

- Set the library versions directly in the `dependency` node.
- Set the `properties` node in `/Utils/pom.xml`.
- Try a different library version.
- Check that the classpath is correct with `mvn dependency:build-classpath -Dmdep.outputFile=cp.txt` and the libraries are there.
- Run `mvn clean compile` in `/`.
- Run `mvn clean compile` in `/Utils`.
- Run `mvn -pl Utils clean compile` in `/`
- Run `mvn clean install -U` in `/`.
- Run `mvn clean install -U` in `/Utils`.

Comment: Try version 3.7.0 of the compiler plugin.

Comment: @Nicolai it worked with that version

Comment: I'm using 3.8.1 with openjdk11 and still getting this

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need at least version 3.7.0 of the [Maven Compiler Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/) to properly handle modules.

Comment: I stopped reading at "3.7.0 of the Maven" and went on a quest to download Maven 3.7.0 (unreleased as of the time of this writing)...

Comment: @Alexandros :D To minimize the chance of this happening in the future, I linked the term, so it stands out as a whole.

Comment: Yeah, I doubt many people will be as hasty as I! :-)

Answer (score -3):

Seems like a jar hell issue. When any module's different versions are added in the code, this appears.check this post out https://carlosbecker.com/posts/maven-dependency-hell/