# Maven module not finding dependencies in IntelliJ

Tags: java, spring-mvc, intellij-idea, module

When I run `mvn install`, I am getting `module not found`. I clean it and install it again but the same error. Let me know if you have any ideas to fix this thank you!

[image]

here is the module-info.java
[image]

I checked the dependencies. they are there:
[image]

here is the project structure:
[image]

Comment: What is th structure of your project?

Comment: Have you tried to run "mvn install" from command line outside IDE?

Comment: @HarryCoder i posted the project structure.

Comment: @y.bedrov i just tried it game the same error

Comment: I would suggest you those links : https://www.baeldung.com/maven-multi-module-project-java-jpms and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50451220/maven-dependency-module-not-found

Comment: @HarryCoder thank you! adding maven-compiler-plugin fixed the error